# How to represent bibliography using bib file

Tags: bibliographies

I have a bib file in txt format in the same directory of all the rest of Latex files.
Here is an example of my file named: Bibliographyforpaper.txt content:

```
 @article{kargupta2004fourier,
      title={A fourier spectrum-based approach to represent decision trees for mining data streams in mobile environments},
      author={Kargupta, Hillol and Park, Byung-Hoon},
      journal={Knowledge and Data Engineering, IEEE Transactions on},
      volume={16},
      number={2},
      pages={216--229},
      year={2004},
      publisher={IEEE}
    }

@article{mukherjee2006privacy,
  title={A privacy-preserving technique for Euclidean distance-based mining algorithms using Fourier-related transforms},
  author={Mukherjee, Shibnath and Chen, Zhiyuan and Gangopadhyay, Aryya},
  journal={The VLDB Journal—The International Journal on Very Large Data Bases},
  volume={15},
  number={4},
  pages={293--315},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer-Verlag New York, Inc.}
}
```

In the LATEX file I use:

```
  \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\newpage
    \bibliography{Bibliographyforpaper}{}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
\nocite*

\end{document}
```

And there is only headline of `References` and no list of the bibliography.
If I add `\printbibliography` and I get an error.

Comment: You need to use `\cite{mukherjee2006privacy}` (or similar) to cite a paper, or `\nocite*` to list all papers, whether they are cited or not.

Comment: When I use the both commands \cite{mukherjee2006privacy} or \nocite* I get a question mark [?]. All I want is to create a full References list at the end of document.

Comment: `\nocite*` will list all references, but you need to run `(pdf/lua/xe)latex` then `bibtex` then `(pdf/lua/xe)latex` again to complete the process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I run (pdf/lua/xe)latex? Just to write it in the file body? I see the same name of my file with an extension of BBL in the directory does it mean something?

Comment: On the command line, you would enter `pdflatex myfile` then `bibtex myfile` and then `pdflatex myfile` again, where `myfile.tex` is the name of your `.tex` file. Alternatively, you could use `lualatex`, `xelatex` or plain old `latex` rather than `pdflatex`. If you are using some sort of IDE (TeXShop, TeXWorks, etc.) there might be a button or menu item to do everything for you.

Comment: Thanks I did it through the menu. In the bibtex process I got This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: MypaperinLATEX-Full2.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file MypaperinLATEX-Full2.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file MypaperinLATEX-Full2.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file MypaperinLATEX-Full2.aux
(There were 3 error messages) and afterwards I ran again pdflatex and it finished OK. When adding \nocite* afterwards I still get an error and no results.

Comment: please fix the latex example in your question to be a _complete_ small example that shows the error, no one can debug code that you have not shown.

Comment: I edited. I added all the options I tried.

Comment: `\nocite` needs to be in the body of the document and you should not have a `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` environment (bibtex will generate one)

Comment: I tried the same way as you mentioned. I re edited and I get an error for the \nocite

Comment: The error I get now is Use of \nocite doesn't match its definition. \nocite*

Comment: Your bib file must have filename extension `.bib`, not `.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\begin{abstract}
zzz
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
zzzz

    \bibliography{Bibliographyforpaper}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, Can you please elaborate the process of compiling and producing the both files. Maybe there lies my error.

Comment: I still get only References headline with the code you used.

Comment: @Avi  save the above as zzz.tex then run `pdflatex zzz` then `bibtex zzz` then `pdflatex zzz` and you will get the output shown